# Optimizing Polygon Search

Tags: python, r, algorithm, polygon

I split de world in X random polygons.

[image]

Then I am given a coordinate C1, for instance (-21.45, 7.10), and I want to attribute the right polygon to this coordinate.

The first solution is to apply my ‘`point_in_polygon`’ algorithm (given a set of coordinates that defines a polygon and a coordinate that defines a point, tell me if the point is inside or not) on each polygon until I find the right one.
But that is very expensive if I have a lot of points to put in a lot of polygons.

An improvement on that relies on the following idea:
To optimise the search, I create a `grid` (a collection) with a step ***n, k*** where I already attribute each pair of coordinates such that:

```
for i=-180 to 180 step n 
    for j = -90 to 90 step k
        grid.add(i,j)
```

Then I create a dictionary, and for each pair in the collection I find the corresponding polygon

```
For each g in grid
    For each p in polygons
        If point_in_polygon(g,p) == True
            my_dict(g) = p
```

Then, when I receive C1, I look for the closest coordinate in my grid, let’s say g1.
Thanks to my_dict, I can get quickly `p1 = my_dict(g1)`
Then I compute `point_in_polygon(C1, p1)` which is likely to be true. If it’s not, I find the closest g which is assigned to a different polygon, and I redo a test. Etc. until I have found the right polygon.

Now, the question is: ***what is the optimal n, k to create the grid?***

So that I can find the right polygon in the minimum number of steps. 
I don’t want it too low, because the search of the closest g which is assigned to a different polygon might be expensive.
I don’t want it too high as well, because then I might be missing some polygons and then the search never converges.

*My intuition is that the smallest polygon is going to give the steps.*

I am not sure if this is a programming problem, a maths problem, or just something I can find empirically, that's why I ask it here.

Any inputs appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me suggest a slight modification to your grid. Currently, you store for each cell the polygon that the cell's center belongs to. Instead, store all the polygons that overlap the cell. Then, whenever you see that a cell has only a single overlapping polygon, you don't need to do any inclusion testing. The grid can be built by methods of conservative [rasterization](http://www.cs.mun.ca/av/old/teaching/cg/notes/raster_poly.pdf) (note that the referenced article is not focused on *conservative* but rather general rasterization).

The efficiency of your grid correlates with the ratio of single-polygon cells and total cells (because this is the probability of not having to perform polygon-inclusion tests). The storage itself is pretty cheap. You can use a dense array and get constant access to the cells. Hence, from a theoretical point of view, you should have as many cells as possible (because as you have more cells, the single-polygon cell ratio increases). In practice, you might find that cache and other memory effects might make large grids impractical. However, there is no good way to know other than test. So, just try with a couple of sizes on a few different machines and try to find a good fit.

If I had to guess, I would say that your cells should be square and have an area of about 1% - 5% of the average polygon area. Also, more compact polygons can be handled more efficiently than many long and thin polygons.

Comment: I like this approach, it makes a lot of sense ! Thank you, I will try to implement this.

Answer (score 1):

Pick any point and draw a line straight down from that point.  The first polygon edge you hit tells you what polygon the point is in.

So, if you don't want to do polygon tests, then instead of dividing the space into a regular grid, first cut it into strips with vertical cuts that go through all polygon intersections.

Now, within each strip none of the polygon edges cross or end, so you can make an ordered list of all those edges from bottom to top.

If you want to find the polygon that contains a point, then, do a binary search using the x coordinate to find the proper strip.  Then in the list of edges that span the strip, you can do a binary search using the y coordinate to find the closest one underneath the point, and that tells you what polygon the point is in.

Google 'trapezoidal decomposition' to find lots of information about similar techniques.